# How to use mysql with a local laravel 8 sail installation

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

I'm studying Laravel 8 and I'm a beginner.
I tried installing it via Sail to take advantage of Docker.
Terminal:

```
curl -s "https://laravel.build/learnlaravel" | bash
cd learnlaravel
./vendor/bin/sail up
```

Now going to localhost I see the Laravel welcome page, everything ok.

if I do:

```
php artisan migrate
```

I get this error:

```
xlf @ MBP16-XLF learnlaravel% php artisan migrate

   Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException

  SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = learnlaravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor / laravel / framework / src / Illuminate / Database / Connection.php: 678
    674▕ // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    675▕ // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    676▕ // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    677▕ catch (Exception $ e) {
  ➜ 678▕ throw new QueryException (
    679▕ $ query, $ this-> prepareBindings ($ bindings), $ e
    680▕);
    681▕}
    682▕
```

can someone kindly explain to me in simple words what i did wrong or what i should do?
is mySQL database already on Docker? how do i log in to create and configure it with the credentials of the .env file?
thank you for your understanding and support :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
./vendor/bin/sail artisan migrate
```

instead of

```
php artisan migrate
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#laravel-sail

Additionally you can install any database manager and connect to your database with this credentials to view and configure it.

Comment: hello elleVan, thanks for your answer, your code returns the same error :(

Comment: @LorenzoFranzone Did you change credentials in the .env file or are they default? https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19522 - maybe you can find a solution here

Comment: thanks, solved with the installation of sequel ace 'cause sequel pro had conflicts with mysql 8

Comment: sequel pro does not seem to work with sail and mysql 8.  But TablePlus worked just fine using the exact same settings.